# What are the three most valuable stores in Mallcrasher?

Tags: payday-2

Vlad wants the mall smashed up.

I have three grenades.

**Which three stores should I use them on to get the most buck for my bang?**

Comment: Do I detect some "blowing things up for science" soon?

Comment: @Unionhawk - As soon as I can figure out an algorithm to let me test it properly.  I think it's going to be X + Y + Z + n*C where C represents skylights.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/644354/whats-the-most-efficient-algorithm-to-determine-the-relative-ordering-of-an-unk

Answer (score 11):

## The Car Showroom is the most valuable store.

After that are the following stores in an unknown order:

- Jewelry
- Computer
- Men's Suits
- Cosmetics

The "Windows" number in the table below indicates how many windows I needed to break after tossing a grenade into each of those stores to reach $50,000. I tested all stores, but did not include results in the table for any store which required me to break more than 20 windows afterward.

*Many civilians were harmed in the making of this table*

```
Store 1    Store 2    Store 3    Windows
Car        Jewelry   Cosmetics      0
Car        Jewelry     Suits        0
Car          Pear     Jewelry       0
Car          Pear    Cosmetics      2
Car          Pear      Suits        3
Pear       Jewelry   Cosmetics      6
Suits      Jewelry     Pear         6
Car       Cosmetics    Suits       12
Jewelry   Cosmetics    Suits       16
Pear      Cosmetics    Suits       20
```

Comment: I don't know how to do the math analysis to order the next four stores.

Comment: Its a good table though I notice it isn't mathemtically rigorous. Presumably because sometimes you destroyed more of a store than others... In particular I note Suits and cosmetics - when with Jewelry and Pair both needed 6 more windows. When with Car and Pair one needed 2 and the other 3. This suggests that they were destroyed a different amount each time. Still useful findings though. Just that the maths on them is inconsistent leaving it only ever as a loose ordering. Very useful to know though. :)

Comment: @Chris It's most definitely **not** rigorous, but it's not a total crapshoot either.  I made sure to throw the grenade in the same place in the store each time and if an area of the store didn't get destroyed, I discarded that data.

Comment: Cool. My only point was that I was trying to treat them as simultaneous equations to work things out precisely to try to take your data and order things and that way lay madness. I may try some more woolly maths to order them but that's harder to do in my head. ;-)

Comment: @Chris What you're saying would only be true if windows were worth $1. Since they're worth much more than that, it could easily be the case that Cosmetics vs. Suits could require the same number of windows to push them over $50k with one pair of other stores, but with a different pair they each require a different number of windows. In fact, as far as I can tell, these numbers are consistent, and imply **Car > Jewelry > Pear > Cosmetics > Suits**.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: Yeah, that's roughly what I was thinking with woolly maths. Trying to do simultaneous equations were each variable is in a range of possibles was too much for my poor head. :)

Answer (score 4):

Using the information determined by @Steve V, we can set up a system of inequalities and use [a linear programming solver](http://www.zweigmedia.com/RealWorld/simplex.html) to determine the value of each store.

Unfortunately, right now there is not enough information to determine exact values, but we can determine ranges:

- **Car**: 17k~21k
- **Jewelry**: 17k~19k
- **Pear**: 16k
- **Cosmetics**: 11k~16k
- **Suits**: 10k~15k

So, you want to bomb **Car**, **Jewelry**, and **Pear** *(computers)* first, in that order.

Comment: For jewelry, are you adding the sum for the stolen goods as well? I don't think stolen counts, and there is little valuble glass to break there. In fact, a nade to the wine shop is a lot more valuable for what I have done. Usually use this destruction route: Roof (~15-20k), wine shop, car shop, pear shop. Add the destruction of windows to get around and I hit the 50k mark with ease.

Comment: @Sharain: No, I'm using the information provided by Steve V, see his post above.